# Why does this code do closed[init[0]][init[1]] instead of closed[init[0]][init[0]]?

Tags: python, algorithm, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I'm reading this First Search Program - Artificial Intelligence for Robotics algorithm and I'm reading a python code of it. Here we have created a closed array to check cells once they expanded and don't expand them again. We defined an array called closed and its size as our grid. The author said it has two values 0 & 1. 0 means open and 1 means closed, but I saw it just zeros.

He marked the starting point 0,0 by 1 until not to check them, but he put the coordinate as 0 and 1 in this line closed[init[0]][init[1]] = 1. Why he put 0 and 1 instead of 0,0?

The python code is here:

```
#grid format
# 0 = navigable space
# 1 = occupied space

grid=[[0,0,1,0,0,0],
      [0,0,1,0,0,0],
      [0,0,0,0,1,0],
      [0,0,1,1,1,0],
      [0,0,0,0,1,0]]

init = [0,0]                         
goal = [len(grid)-1,len(grid[0])-1]   


delta=[[-1, 0],      #up
       [ 0,-1],      #left
       [ 1, 0],      #down
       [ 0, 1]]      #right

delta_name = ['^','<','V','>']        #The name of above actions
cost = 1

def search():
    #open list elements are of the type [g,x,y] 
    closed = [[0 for row in range(len(grid[0]))] for col in range(len(grid))]

    #We initialize the starting location as checked
    closed[init[0]][init[1]] = 1
    # we assigned the cordinates and g value
    x = init[0]
    y = init[1]
    g = 0
    #our open list will contain our initial value
    open = [[g,x,y]]


    found = False #flag that is set when search complete
    resign= False #Flag set if we can't find expand

    #print('initial open list:')
    #for i in range(len(open)):
            #print('  ', open[i])
    #print('----')


    while found is False and resign is False:
        #Check if we still have elements in the open list
        if len(open)==0: #If our open list is empty
            resign=True
            print('Fail')
            print('############# Search terminated without success')
        else: 
            #if there is still elements on our list
            #remove node from list
            open.sort()       
            open.reverse()    #reverse the list
            next = open.pop() 
            #print('list item')
            #print('next')

            #Then we assign the three values to x,y and g. Which is our expantion
            x = next[1]
            y = next[2]
            g = next[0]

            #Check if we are done

            if x == goal[0] and y == goal[1]:
                found = True
                print(next) #The three elements above this if
                print('############## Search is success')
            else:
                #expand winning element and add to new open list
                for i in range(len(delta)): 
                    x2 = x+delta[i][0]
                    y2 = y+delta[i][1]
                    #if x2 and y2 falls into the grid
                    if x2 >= 0 and x2 < len(grid) and y2 >=0 and y2 <= len(grid[0])-1:
                        #if x2 and y2 not checked yet and there is not obstacles
                        if closed[x2][y2] == 0 and grid[x2][y2] == 0:
                            g2 = g+cost #we increment the cose
                            open.append([g2,x2,y2])#we add them to our open list
                            #print('append list item')
                            #print([g2,x2,y2])
                            #Then we check them to never expand again
                            closed[x2][y2] = 1

search()
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you asking "why does this code do `closed[init[0]][init[1]]` instead of `closed[init[0,1]]`?"? Or are you asking why does this code do `closed[init[0]][init[1]]` instead of ``closed[init[0]][init[0]]``?"? Or are you asking something else?

Comment: @ Kevin Yes sir, the second one  why does this code do closed[init[0]][init[1]] instead of closed[init[0]][init[0]]?" I mean this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> he put the coordinate as 0 and 1 in this line closed[init[0]][init[1]] = 1

`closed[init[0]][init[1]]` does not mean "set the value at coordinates (0,1) to 1". It means "using `init[0]` as the x coordinate and `init[1]` at the y coordinate, set the value to 1". `init[0]` is 0, and `init[1]` is 0, so `closed[init[0]][init[1]] = 1` sets `closed[0][0]` to 1.

Suppose the starting coordinate was `init = [2,5]`. It would be incorrect to change the line to `closed[init[2]][init[5]] = 1`. This would crash with an IndexError, because `init` only has two elements, so you can only index it with 0 or 1.

Comment: Thank you so much sir for explanation. So, you mean [init] has just zero or one. Here took the value of them 0 and 0 and then these values represent the coordinate of the starting point, then set it to 1.